# MYSQL : Improving query perfomance on join with order by clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables which contains the daily activities of a user . I have two join these tables and select top ten ids from this table .

Table 1 : **buildlog**

```
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| NAME           | varchar(50)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ID             | int(11)                | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DATE_AND_TIME  | datetime               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| COMMENT        | mediumtext             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Number Of Rows** : 276186

Table 2 : **reports**

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| r_id          | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id            | int(15)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| label         | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Number Of Rows** : 134058

If I am using only join query with this two tables using `id` it comes very quickly .

**Query 1**:

```
select  buildlog.id,reports.label from buildlog join reports on reports.id = buildlog.id limit 10\G
```

**Query Time** : 10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

If I add order by to get latest ten build ids,label it takes 1 to 2 minutes to execute .

**Query 2** :

```
select  buildlog.id,reports.label from buildlog join reports on reports.id = buildlog.id order by buildlog.id desc limit 10\G
```

Query Time : `10 rows in set (0.98 sec)`

order by column is an primary key `buildlog.id` . So, It's already indexed why It takes more time to execute this query ? . Can anyone suggest how can I optimize this?

Comment: you could look at the execution plan, but sorting will always take more time. I don't know if it's normal for your number of records though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * FROM (
    SELECT
      buildlog.id,
      reports.label
    FROM
      buildlog
    JOIN
      reports
    ON
      reports.id = buildlog.id
) AS myval_new
ORDER BY id DESC limit 10
```

The slow down comes because it is probably choosing to do the ordering before doing the join. Doing the order by in an outer query forces it to only order the selected items.

Comment: Hi , This query won't solve the problem because it store all rows using join query into a new temporary table . That means my table join result is 2 lakh rows . It store into the temporary table and applies the order by in  the temporary table . This query will be a slower one than previous .